# Python comparison between two list using greater operator

Tags: python, list

Can anyone help me explain why the first and second return different results? I think the second should return 2 as well.

```
In [15]: bisect.bisect([0,3], 3)
Out[15]: 2

In [16]: bisect.bisect([[0, 0], [3, 50]], [3])
Out[16]: 1
```

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types

Comment: They have very different arguments as input. You'll need to give us more context, like what you tried to do and what you expected it does.

Comment: But, `[3] < [3, 50]` is true, because for lists of different lengths, the longer list is always greater if their common elements are otherwise equal: *If one sequence is an initial sub-sequence of the other, the shorter sequence is the smaller (lesser) one.*

Answer (score 1):

The detailed answer:

The indicated command returns the index where to insert item x in list a, preserving the order, assuming a is sorted.

To calc this position, a binary search is performed, and in each iteration a comparison is made between a value in the list and the value to be inserted.

The first difference I notice is that in the first example you provide a list of numbers and a numeric value to input. In the second case, it's a list of lists, and a list to insert.

This affects the result of comparisons, more specifically when comparing the given value with index 1 of the lists.

In the case of the list of numbers, we have [0, 3] and 3, so the comparison on index 1 is: 3 < 3, which returns False.

In the case of the list of lists, we have [[0, 0], [3, 50]] and [3], and the comparison in index 1 is [3] < [3, 50].

Comparing lists follows a slightly different method, following the lexicographical order, as can be seen at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types.

In the case [3] it is a subsequence of [3, 50], so the result of the comparison [3] < [3, 50] returns True.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation that you linked:

> If one sequence is an initial sub-sequence of the other, the shorter sequence is the smaller (lesser) one.

This is basically the same way that a dictionary sorts words (a book, not a Python `dict`). All other things being equal, a shorter sequence is considered less than a longer one. Therefore, `[3]` comes before `[3, 50]`.